# Custom Tabbar Controller for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I try to create framework for iPhone and try to implement Custom Tabbar Controller in my framework. Any one can help me to create custom tab bar controller for iPhone. I mean programmatically add tab bar controller.

Comment: what u want to do., How to add TabbarController programmatically (OR) customTabBar ??

Comment: there are plenty framework of tabbar out there. try look in http://cocoacontrols.com/.

Comment: Are you going to create framework !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To create tab bar give this code in AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3;

  viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewControllerXibname" bundle:nil];
  viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerXibname" bundle:nil];
  viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewControllerXibname" bundle:nil];


  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


   self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor darkTextColor];

  [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]]; //change selected image color on tabbatItem

  self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

  [self.tabBarController.tabBar setOpaque:YES];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This links may be helpful to you:

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-can-i-add-tabs-programmatically-to-uitabbar/201/

http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-custom-tabbar-controller-bctabbarcontroller.html

Or

The other option is - you can go with the custom buttons which acts like an UITabbarController.

Enjoy Coding :)

Mrunal